# Rails 5 render JSON with object including decorated association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, draper

My Rails 5 app has a Ride model and a Waypoint model, where **one Ride has many Waypoints**.

Also I have a waypoint decorator, that decorates some of the waypoint fields.

In my Rails app I want to return a list of rides and all there nested waypoints.

```
@api_v1_rides = Ride.all
render json: {
      status: 200,
      rides: @api_v1_rides
}.to_json( :include => [:waypoints])
```

Works great.

But I want to return the decorated waypoints, so what I tried was:

```
@api_v1_rides = Ride.all
render json: {
      status: 200,
      rides: @api_v1_rides
}.to_json( :include => [:waypoints.decorate])
```

But this gives me an error saying that decorate is not a function of waypoints.
I am using the Drape Gem to decorate and it works just fine in other parts of the app.

Answer (score 1):

for complex json structure i would recommend you to use this gem 
[active model serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)